# How to apply separate to several columes with same actions in R?

Tags: r

I want to separate one column into 4 columnes by "-", keep the new 4 columnes, drop the original colume, rename the new 4 columnes. Then apply the same action to several columes.

I used the stupid way...I tried to write function with `separate` and `paste`, but failed...

[image: data sample]

*R code as below*:

```
tabled <- table_d %>% 
   separate("A3 CAB PA",into=c("A3 CAB PA_count","A3 CAB PA_sumkm","A3 CAB PA_drive","A3 CAB PA_drive2"),sep="-") %>%
   separate("A4 Allroad B9",into=c("A4 Allroad B9_count","A4 Allroad B9_sumkm","A4 Allroad B9_drive","A4 Allroad B9_drive2"),sep="-") %>%
   separate("A5 Cabriolet B9",into=c("A5 Cabriolet B9_count","A5 Cabriolet B9_sumkm","A5 Cabriolet B9_drive","A5 Cabriolet B9_drive2"),sep="-") %>%
```

and so on...

Is that possible to define a `function(x)` and use `lapply(data[,-1],function(x))` to replace the long code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a data sample with your structure

```
library(tidyr) 

A <- c("7-4-5-9", NA) 
B <- c("6-4-5-1", "7-8-6-3") 
dat <- data.frame(A,B, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #example data

for (col in names(dat)){  # you will propably need to assign a subset of columns with something like wanted_cols %in% names(dat))  

    namecol1 <- paste(col, "count", sep ="_") 
    namecol2 <- paste(col, "sumkm", sep ="_") 
    namecol3 <- paste(col, "drive", sep ="_") 
    namecol4 <- paste(col, "drive2", sep ="_") #set the wanted column structure
    cols <- rlang::sym(col) 

    dat <- dat %>% separate(!!cols, into = c(namecol1, namecol2, namecol3, namecol4), sep = "-", remove = TRUE) # separate and remove the original column 
}
```

Comment: @ArielZhang your question was nice, because it is not always simple to associate dplyr and loops/functions. But in the future, it would be very nice to share a sample of your data that someone can copy directly into their console. The usual way is to copy the output of dput(yourdata[c(1:10),]).

Comment: sorry for the late reply, well noted, thanks for your advice.